# How to remove word in string array

Tags: c#, replace

How to remove word in string array

```
var array= new string []
               {"windows!!1!!","dual+sim!!3!!","32+gb!!2!!","Intel+i5!!2!!"};
```

Output array

```
var Output-array= new string []
                   {"windows","dual sim","32 gb","Intel i5"};
```

How can do like this in single line of code in C#

Comment: @MaciejLos : Not any idea how to do

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your pattern is always `!![one digit]!!`

Regex should be the easiest way to solve this. And a `Replace("+", " ")` to replace `+` characters with a space.

```
string[] array = new string[] { "windows!!1!!", "dual+sim!!3!!", "32+gb!!2!!", "Intel+i5!!2!!" };
string[] result = array.Select(x => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(x, @"!!\d!!", "").Replace("+", " ")).ToArray();
```

Comment: better replace the pattern with `@"!!.*!!"` nice answer though

Comment: yes but you should ask a new question for that, that has nothing to do with the initial question

Comment: Please reply buddy :(

Answer (score 0):

While not a single liner. No need to understand RegEx,and an extension method that should be in your toolkit anyway. Only assumption is a "!!" being your terminator for the string you wish to extract.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get string value before [first] a.
/// </summary>
public static string Before(this string value, string a)
{
   int posA = value.IndexOf(a);
   if (posA == -1)
   {
       return "";
   }
   return value.Substring(0, posA);
}

var myList = new List<string>();
foreach var element in array
{
    myList.Add(element.Before("!!"));
}

var outPutArray = myList.ToArray();
```